# Generate a sequence of the last days of all previous N months with a given month

Tags: python

Given a `'%Y-%m'` (e.g. `2022-03`), what's a good way to get a list of the last days of its previous `N` (e.g. `5`) months with desired results:

```
['2021-10-31', '2021-11-30', '2021-12-31', '2022-01-31', '2022-02-28']
```

Comment: Make a sequence of 1st days, `2022-03-01, 2022-04-01`, ... and subtract one day from them.  `datetime.date`, `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.timedelta` are relevant modules in the standard libraries.

Comment: Cool. Sounds doable. My brain was stuck with generating the last days using something like: `[str(k)+'-'+str(m)+'-'+str(calendar.monthrange(k, m)[1]) for k in range(2022, 2023) for m in range(1, 13)]` which over-complicates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured `Pandas` already has `Month End (M)` freq in its builtin `date_range` function:

```
>>> end = datetime.strptime('2022-03', '%Y-%m')
>>> start = end - pd.DateOffset(months=5)
>>> pd.date_range(start, end, freq='M')
DatetimeIndex(['2021-10-31', '2021-11-30', '2021-12-31', '2022-01-31', '2022-02-28'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you can use a list comprehension to generate a list of previous month *starts*, then subtract one day from each of them.

```
def previous_month_ends(date, months):
  year, month, day = [int(x) for x in date.split('-')]
  d = datetime.date(year, month, day)
  t = datetime.timedelta(1)
  s = datetime.date(year, month, 1)
  return [(x - t).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
          for m in range(months - 1, -1, -1)
          for x in (datetime.date(s.year, s.month - m, s.day) if s.month > m else \
                    datetime.date(s.year - 1, s.month - (m - 12), s.day),)]
```

You'll want to do some math to ensure you handle the previous dates going into the previous year(s). The above will need to be modified to handle lartge values for `months`.